# Evaluating $\int e^{4x}\sin(6x)\,dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I use a $u$-substitution and set $u$ equal to $e^{4x}$ and $dv$ equal to $\sin(6x)\,dx$. Any advice is greatly appreciated.
$$\int e^{4x}\sin(6x)\,dx$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial.  To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: That's not $u$-substitution, that's integration by parts...

Comment: @HansLundmark Re your 1st comment - agreed.  I think that this is what the OP intended.  In IBP, you set $u$ equal to part of the integrand and $dv$ equal to the other part (at least that is what I was taught 50 years ago).

Comment: Note : I believe Hans' duplicate does the job well, a change of constants can easily be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I = \displaystyle\int e^{4x}\sin(6x)\mathrm{d}x$ . Integrate by parts twice instead of once.

You should find that $I = a(x) + bI$ (where $a(x)$ is some function of $x$ you determine by integrating by parts). From which you can compute what $I$ is.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int e^{4x}\sin(6x)\,dx$$
$\displaystyle u=e^{4x}\Rightarrow u'=4e^{4x}\qquad v'=\sin(6x)\Rightarrow v=-\cos(6x)/6$
$$I=-\frac{e^{4x}\cos(6x)}{6}+\frac46\int e^{4x}\cos(6x)\,dx$$
$\displaystyle u=e^{4x}\Rightarrow u'=4e^{4x}\qquad v'=\cos(6x)\Rightarrow v=\sin(6x)/6$

I'll let you finish it off from here

Answer (score 0):

If you integrate by parts, then integrate by parts again, you get
$$
\int e^{4x}\sin(6x)\,dx = \Big(\text{something}_1\Big) - \left(\big(\text{something}_2\big) \times \int e^{4x}\sin(6x)\,dx \right)
$$
Therefore
$$
\int e^{4x}\sin(6x)\,dx + \left(\big(\text{something}_2\big) \times \int e^{4x}\sin(6x)\,dx \right) = \Big(\text{something}_1\Big)
$$
And then
$$
\Big(\big(\text{something}_2 \big)+1\Big) \int e^{4x}\sin(6x)\,dx = \Big(\text{something}_1\Big)
$$
Then divide both sides by $\Big(\big(\text{something}_2\big)+1\Big).$

Alternatively, you can write $e^{4x}\sin(6x) = e^{4x}\cdot\dfrac{e^{6ix}-e^{-6ix}} {2i}$ and go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int e^{4x}\sin(6x)\,dx=\Im \left(\int e^{4x}e^{6ix}\,dx\right)=\Im \left(\int e^{(4+6i)x}\,dx\right)=\Im \left(\frac{e^{(4+6i)x} }{4+6i }\right)$$ Working the complex numbers
$$\frac{e^{(4+6i)x} }{4+6i }=\left(\frac{1}{13}-\frac{3 i}{26}\right) e^{4x}\left(\cos(6x)+i\sin(6x)\right)$$ and for the same price, you have the integral with the cosine.